# Solve Differential Equation $(xe^{xy})dx + (1 + xe^{xy}) dy = 0$

Tags: differential

I'm trying to solve this but can't seem to find the answer. I found out that it is not an exact differential equation so I tried to find the integrating factor but can't seem to find the correct result

Comment: What was your integrating fatcor? Show your work

Comment: Maybe correct equation is $(ye^{xy})dx + (1 + xe^{xy}) dy = 0$ ?

Comment: @user71207 it was like [this](https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/653206818759376916/834662611835682817/IMG_20210422_123054.jpg) which does not seem to be correct at all. I dunno what to do now T_T

Comment: @AleksasDomarkas I dont think so, the problem is exactly as it looks like in the assignment

Comment: @user71207 yea that one was wrong. But, maybe the question is wrong too just like what AleksasDomarkas said. 

You know what guys, it doesn't matter now cause the due date already passed. Thanks for the response tho 